# Windows Forms Web Browser control doesn't interpret "do" as an identifier

Tags: javascript, winforms

I am trying to use the JavaScript library Rx in a web app that will eventually be embedded in a Windows Forms WebBrowser control. When I run the web app in Windows Forms, I get an error amounting to the fact that "do" is not an identifier in JavaScript. This error doesn't occur in Internet Explorer. The gist is this:

```
function Widget() {
    this.test = 42;
}
Widget.prototype.do = function() {
    console.log("You did it!");
}
```

This script works just fine in pretty much any browser, but the WebBrowser control's script interpreter will say "expected identifier" on `do` in there. I suspect it's interpreting it as a keyword instead of as an identifier.

This is a problem as external libraries, including Rx, use `do` as the name of a function. How can I work around this such that we can use whatever libraries we need in the Windows Forms WebBrowser with minimal hacking, if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the page needs a meta tag to get the WebBrowser to use a modern renderer. It uses IE 7 or something by default.

Just had to add this to the head:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```